# How to enforce enum member as argument type in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

Say I have an enum like so:

```
enum Color {red, green, blue}
```

And I then define some function that takes an argument of this enum type:

```
function foo(c: Color) {
  return c
}
```

Unless otherwise specified the enum members `red`, `green` and `blue` will take on the values 0, 1 and 2 respectively. So I can use my function like this:

```
foo(Color.red)

// or

foo(0)
```

But something like `foo('bar')` will fail.

So far, so good. But I find that `foo(9999)` compiles just fine, which is not what I'd expect given that 9999 is not equal to any member of `Color`.

In fact, any number can be passed to `foo`, including floats, and the compiler has no problem.

Is there a way to get type safety for enum members so that I'm only allowed to pass values that are in the enum?